# Resetting MultipleObjectMixin pagination when filtering in get_queryset

Tags: django, pagination, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm using a custom mixin to apply a filter to the queryset of a class based view that is paginated with MultipleObjectMixin. When I apply the filter such that the current page outside the range of the dataset, I obviously get a 404. What I want to do is catch this exception and have it redirect to the new last page instead.

My get_queryset for the view in question:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    filters = self.build_location_filter()
    if not filters == None:
        return models.Account.corporateAccounts(locations=self.build_location_filter)
    else:
        return models.Account.corporateAccounts()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return super(MyView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    except Http404:
        if kwargs['page'] > self.paginator.num_pages:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('this_view_paged', kwargs={'page': self.paginator.num_pages}))
        else:
            # re-raise Http404, as the reason for the 404 was not that maximum pages was exceeded
            raise Http404(_(u"Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.")
                      % {'class_name': self.__class__.__name__})
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry. I really thought that Django added `paginator` as an instance variable. It *really* sucks that it doesn't, because it makes this 100 times more difficult than it needs to be. The paginator is squirreled away in `paginate_queryset`, which is actually where the `Http404` gets raised from. That means, you can't even call this method to get your paginator, as all you'll ever get from it is an exception. So, you have to go deeper, unfortunately duplicating some of the Django view logic, which I *hate* to do, but it's the only path forward I can see. Since we're resorting to code duplication, regardless, I'm now overriding the entire `paginate_queryset` method. The new code is copied straight from the Django source, with modifications noted in commented sections (I've left the original code above intact for posterity):

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
        """
        Paginate the queryset, if needed.
        """
        paginator = self.get_paginator(queryset, page_size, allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
        page = self.kwargs.get('page') or self.request.GET.get('page') or 1
        try:
            page_number = int(page)
        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            else:
                raise Http404(_(u"Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int."))
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            # Moving this line after the try/except block because DRY
            #return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
        except InvalidPage:
            # This used to raise a 404, but we're replacing this functionality
            #raise Http404(_(u'Invalid page (%(page_number)s)') % {
            #                    'page_number': page_number
            #})
            page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
```

Comment: I'm getting an attribute error saying that " 'GroupsList' object has no attribute 'paginator' ", with Groupslist being the name of the view class, at the "if kwargs['page'] > self.paginator.num_pages:" line. I'm paginating the view by setting MultipleObjectMixin's paginate_by to 20, if that helps.

Comment: Just be aware that this completely replaces the Django version of `paginate_queryset`, so if they change something in a future version, upgrading *could* cause your view to stop functioning. Now, based on the code that's here, I severely doubt whatever changes are made, if ever any are, would actually cause a problem, but it's something to note.